# What yeast is in White Labs WLP080 Cream Ale Blend?

Tags: yeast

Has anyone used the Cream Ale blend from WhiteLabs?  I used it recently and am surprised at the lack of flocculation.  The beer has been in a cold keg for a month and its still fairly cloudy.  Was just wondering what yeast strains may be contributing to the lack of flocculation.

When I normally brew this beer with US05 or WLP001 it would normally have cleared by now.

Comment: The rumor is that it is a blend of WLP 810 (San Francisco Lager) and WLP 029 (Kolsch/German Ale). The WLP 810 is a great floccer. White Labs identifies WLP 029 as medium flocculation.

Comment: Just used this yeast. Lowered to temp to 34°F to cold crash for 2 days and in it nice and clear. Also took care of the sulphur smell which I didn't expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chino Brews says The WhiteLab site refers to this blend as "Flocculation: Medium". I have used other yeasts describe similarly they have all cleared over the course of a month.

It may be the yeast, in which case using isinglass would help.

As with most things in brewing there are myriad reasons other than the yeast as to why your brew may be cloudy take a look here for a description them: http://byo.com/hops/item/944-just-fine

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use gelatin to fine this beer. Gelatin works great at fining, and is especially effective when the beer is in the keg and at serving temperature already. (If you want to get rid of chill haze, the chill haze has to be present!)